# Webapi 2 does not return list in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

```
public IEnumerable<Word> GetWords()
{
    return db.Words.ToList();
}
```

I need this output in XML using webapi2; I already googled and try

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "text/xml");
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

It returns data only in JSON.

Also I updated the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml`

How can I get it in XML?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

set both the HTTP Accept and Content-Type headers to "application/xml".

Answer (score 0):

I set up an empty Web API project and issued a GET request with PostMan. Out of the box the Web API returned XML like

```
 <ArrayOfstring xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
      <string>value1</string>
      <string>value2</string>
 </ArrayOfstring>
```

for the default example controller. The trick is to set the Accept Header in the request.

```
 Accept: text/xml (or application/xml)
```

Keep in mind that the stated line

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

removes the media type. So it will disable XML output (and not enable it).